# MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax workbench 8.0

Tags: sql, mariadb, ddl

I need some help to with this sql

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 4

SQL Code:

```
    ALTER TABLE `pro_idocs`.`doc` 
    ADD COLUMN `template_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `online`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `online` `online` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1-deafted,2-pending flow,3-approved,4-reopened,9-closed,\n' ,
    ADD INDEX `fk_doc_template1_idx` (`template_id` ASC) VISIBLE
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: What is PRECISE server version? On 10.5.6 the query executes successfully https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=89c302c3f47598a0f1ee12f15ee096a5 , on 10.4.15 gives provided error message. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=89c302c3f47598a0f1ee12f15ee096a5

Comment: Workbench is a client... execute `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: it was 10.4.13.I'll try to update it.

Comment: Read accepted answer by the link...